# Creating UserController.php with artisan is failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Following along with *Learning Laravel 4 Application Development - Hardik Danger*.

I attempt to create my first controller with artisan by doing the following:

```
php artisan Usercontroller:make users
```

And I get an error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                        
  There are no commands defined in the "Usercontroller" namespace.  

  Did you mean this?                                                
      controller
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct command should be:

```
php artisan controller:make UsersController
```

Comment: For Laravel 5, checkout Raj's answer below.

Comment: This is the way in Laravel 4, but in Laravel 5 you should use it backwards php artisan make:controller UsersController, like @Raj explained it below

Answer (score 29):

Laravel 5

```
php artisan make:controller UsersController
```

Answer (score 2):

or try

```
php artisan make:controller UsersController
```

Comment: First of, I didn't down vote, but I can see why it was. Consider reading this guide on how to answer a SO question properly. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer